# Using Pre-Compiled Templates with Sammy

Tags: javascript, templates, sammy.js, client-templates, brunch

Sammy has a lot of features for working with template languages. However, when working with [brunch](http://brunch.io/), the server pre-compiles all the templates for me, which is very much desired.

So they're all available as java-functions, how can I use those with Sammy?

Comment: @aliona Nope. I'm half inclined starting my own framework that allows it.